# Type missmatch error in while loop

Tags: excel, vba

Somebody please help me. I'm getting error when it enters into while loop. See the below code.(The first file runs correctly. hoever when it enters the loop error will generate)

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A:E").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
        "=*CHASE RETURN DATE*", Operator:=xlAnd
```

Full Code is below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CombineTextFiles()
    Dim FilesToOpen
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim wkbAll As Workbook
    Dim wkbTemp As Workbook
    Dim sDelimiter As String
    Dim erow
    Dim IRow As Long

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    sDelimiter = "|"

    FilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
      (FileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt), *.txt", _
      MultiSelect:=True, Title:="Text Files to Open")

    If TypeName(FilesToOpen) = "Boolean" Then
        MsgBox "No Files were selected"
        GoTo ExitHandler
    End If

    x = 1
    Set wkbTemp = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FilesToOpen(x))
    wkbTemp.Sheets(1).Copy
    Set wkbAll = ActiveWorkbook
    wkbTemp.Close (False)
    wkbAll.Worksheets(x).Columns("A:A").TextToColumns _
      Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 2), Array(47, 2), Array(72, 2), Array(93, 2), Array(103, 2)) _
        , TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
        Cells.Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("A:E").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=*$*", _
        Operator:=xlAnd
        ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
Workbooks("Test.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, 4))
'To pick the date
wkbAll.Worksheets(x).Activate
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("A:E").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
        "=*CHASE RETURN DATE*", Operator:=xlAnd
With ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns(4).Offset(1, 0).Resize(Rows.Count - 1, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
End With
 Selection.Copy
 Workbooks("Test.xlsm").Activate
 Sheets("Sheet1").Select
erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(erow, 6), Cells(erow, 6))

'Sum Amount
wkbAll.Worksheets(x).Activate
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("A:E").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:= _
        "=*$*", Operator:=xlAnd
With ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns(3).Offset(1, 0).Resize(Rows.Count - 1, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
End With
Selection.Copy
 Workbooks("Test.xlsm").Activate
 Sheets("Sheet1").Select
erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(erow, 2), Cells(erow, 2))

    x = x + 1

    While x <= UBound(FilesToOpen)
        Set wkbTemp = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FilesToOpen(x))
        With wkbAll
            wkbTemp.Sheets(1).Move After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
            .Worksheets(x).Columns("A:A").TextToColumns _
              Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 2), Array(47, 2), Array(72, 2), Array(93, 2), Array(103, 2)) _
        , TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
        Cells.Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("A:E").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=*$*", _
        Operator:=xlAnd
        ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
Workbooks("Test.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).Row
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, 4))
Workbooks(Worksheets(x)).Activate
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("A:E").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
        "=*CHASE RETURN DATE*", Operator:=xlAnd ' This is where I'm getting error as "Type missmatch"
        End With
        x = x + 1
    Wend

ExitHandler:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set wkbAll = Nothing
    Set wkbTemp = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume ExitHandler
End Sub
```

Comment: ++ for the effort and research into the question, and pointing out the relevant line (but you should start indenting your code better to make it a easier for others to read - try to make nice distinct sections with vertical  spaces, and use nested indenting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add variable as wkball before the activation of worksheet. Sorry my mistake

```
wkbAll.Worksheets(x).Activate
```